# Saving Cookies To A Javascript Associative Array

Tags: arrays, cookies, associative

I'm having trouble with cookies. I have a bunch of links that when clicked on, create a cookie. For each link I need to be able to save that cookie to an associative array. The tricky part is the cookie values are dynamically created. We don't know what they are until they are clicked on (using the id attribute).

Here is the click function I'm using to create the cookie:

$j('a.createCookie').click(function(e) {

```
 var cookieName = "InsightsCookie";

 var cookieValue = $j(this).attr("id");

 $j.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {expires: 365, path: '/'});
```

});

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To save the cookies to a global associative array, you would do something like this:

```
var my_global_assoc_array = {};
$j('a.createCookie').click(function(e) {
 var cookieName = "InsightsCookie";
 var cookieValue = $j(this).attr("id");
 $j.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {expires: 365, path: '/'});

 // save just the value of the cookie
 my_global_assoc_array[cookieName] = cookieValue;     

 // or save the whole cookie because you may want to know more about the cookie path, cookie expiration, etc
 my_global_assoc_array[cookieName] = $j.cookie(cookieName);
});
```

Then at some later point, you can iterate over what's been collected in your assoc array:

```
for(var i in my_global_assoc_array)
    console.log("cookie name = " + i + ", cookie value = " + i);
```

I'm confused about this part of your question:  "The tricky part is the cookie values are dynamically created."  Since the cookie values are just values in the my_global_assoc_array, why do you need to know what the values are beforehand?

**Update**

If you want a single cookie to contain all the values of my_global_assoc_array then use a loop in the set cookie routine.  Something like this:

```
var my_global_assoc_array = {};

$j('a.createCookie').click(function(e) {
 var cookieName = "InsightsCookie";
 var cookieValue = $j(this).attr("id");

 // save all values of the cookie in an assoc array to uniqueify the list.
 my_global_assoc_array[cookieValue] = 0;     
 // temporarily turn cookieValue into an Array, add all the cookieValues to it and
 // use join to stringify it to a CSV value of the values.
 cookieValue = new Array();
 for(var i in my_global_assoc_array)
    cookieValue.push(i);
 cookieValue = cookieValue.join(',');
 // store cookieValue which is now a CSV list of cookieValues
 $j.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {expires: 365, path: '/'});

});
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for your response! I'm new at this so everything I'd found for examples were ones that knew all of the values already. Instead of an associative array, is there a way I could add the values to one cookie with each lick on a link? So the end result would be "InsightsCookie: cookieValue, cookieValue, cookieValue, cookieValue" and with each click I could add a new value to the cookie?

Comment: That was dumb of me.  Check the Update again, I edited it.  In the for loop, I was adding the value of my_global_assoc_array[i], instead, we just want the value of i.

Comment: That didn't work either. It just puts the one value in the cookie. If I click on another article it replaces the existing value. I need it to add to it after a comma is inserted.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry - I'm a newbie.

Comment: Oh and I tried to upvote your answer... but it says I'm not reputable enough yet. LOL! :)

Comment: Genie looks into cloudy ball and pronouces...."Some helpful links to docs and examples on how to read/write cookies in JavaScript shall soon come your way"...  Later, you awake, not knowing where you are but find a piece of paper with the following.... http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/     http://webhole.net/2010/07/10/jquery-cookies-example/      You're almost there!!!

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at those before. :) I must be retarded or something.

Comment: Ah ok, well... try this.   my_global_assoc_array[$.cookie('InsightsCookie')] = 0;

Comment: There can be some hidden gotchas in there as far as the data that is saved to the cookie, for example you can get dup values in some cases, but it should help you on your way.